# Connect SendInBlue to Magento 1.9

Tags: api, magento, magento-1.9, sendinblue

I would like to connect Magento 1.9 to SendInBlue in order to synchronize all contacts of Magento into SendInBlue.
However, it looks like the plugin proposed here is not available anymore: https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/209578645--Installing-the-Magento-1-Plugin

Does anyone know a way to download it anyway or know a simple way to connect Magento 1.9 to SendInBlue ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone want to do the same, just contact the customer service and they'll gently give you the .tar.gz of the extension ;)